# Problem to control div with blueprint css

Tags: css, xhtml, blueprint-css

I´m having a problem with divs when I´m trying to apply background-color to #header for example so it will cover all of the header.
it dosen't show any changes that I made to the css of the #header, #maincontainer and more can you please help me I have tried so many things and nothings seems to work.

Here is the Html sample :

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="span-24 showgrid">
   <div id="header">
   <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="Iris logo"></div>
   <div id="slogan">
   <h1>Íris</h1>
   <h2>Ættleiðingartengd fræðsla</h2>
   </div>
   <div id="searchbar"><input class="text" onfocus="this.value=&#39;&#39;" type="text"     name="searchbar" value="Leita.."></div>
    </div><!-- end .header -->
```

Here is the rest of the HTML if you prefer to see to all : 
http://pastebin.com/8AyENrdn

Comment: Can you provide the CSS? That's as important as the HTML part. Also, including a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is useful for viewing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell from what you have described and no CSS - Try this

```
#header {overflow:hidden;background:#eee;}
```

Comment: Glad to help. The reason why your background might not have been showing is due to floated elements within the parent element.